# Powershell 3.0: COPY-ITEM Filter or Include options not working

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-cmdlet, copy-item

Does the -Filter or -Include parameter work for anyone when using Powershell 3.0?  I've tried both of the following commands:

```
Copy-Item -Path c:\temp -Include "*.TXT" -Destination C:\temp2
```

and

```
Copy-Item -Path c:\temp -Filter "*.TXT" -Destination C:\temp2
```

Actually, for the -Filter option, an empty "temp" folder gets created in c:\TEMP2.  I know that the following command works:

```
Copy-Item -Path c:\temp\*.TXT -Destination C:\temp2
```

But just wondering if anyone has come across this issue before?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is because the item that you are feeding into Copy-Item is the *folder*, not the *files* inside the folder.

When you execute:

```
Copy-Item -Path c:\temp -Include "*.txt" -Destination C:\temp2
```

You are saying: Copy Item, where the Path is the folder c:\temp. The only item that is selected to copy *is* the directory c:\temp. Then we say, only -Include items that match "*.txt". Since the only item (the folder "temp") does not match the pattern, we do nothing.

To prove this, let's change the Include filter to "temp", and re-execute it:

```
Copy-Item -Path c:\temp -Include "temp" -Destination C:\temp2
```

Voilà! in the destination folder, we have a new empty folder: c:\temp2\temp. (It's empty because the only item we told it to copy was the folder "temp", we did not tell it to copy anything else)

So for part 2, When you execute:

```
Copy-Item -Path c:\temp\*.txt -Destination C:\temp2
```

It works because you are saying, with the *.txt, iterate through all items in the directory that match the pattern *.txt, feed those paths to Copy-Item, and copy to the destination.

To prove this, let's change it, and specify an include filter:

```
Copy-Item -Path c:\temp\* -Include "*.txt" -Destination C:\temp2
```

We are saying here, get all items in the folder c:\temp (i.e. we are getting all the items *inside* the folder c:\temp, and not *the* folder c:\temp), filter them by only including items that match "*.txt", and copy to the destination.

Comment: That was easy.  Thx for the tip.  Merry Christmas!

Comment: I like this answer. I wish it worked. I'm using `-Recursive`, which seems to break `-Include`. Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround? Thanks!